# command to create file name with date as postfix using shell script

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I need to create the dump file name with the current date as postfix to the file name in shell script.

I tried below command in my script but that did not work.

Can any one suggest me the way :

`... dump_'$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')'.txt`

**BACKGROUND:**
I feel Its not require to mention details about the script as it is not completely related to the question but still I want to give some information.
My script is copying some lines from other `*txt` files and creating a separate `dump.txt` file .But I want to mention date as a postfix to the dump filename to understand the history about the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# summary script

echo "Summary!"

shopt -s extglob

for f in */data/*txt; do tail -n+5 $f | head -1 | tr -d "\n"; echo " $f |"; done > dump.txt
sed -nE '/[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]?[[:digit:]]%/P' dump.txt > dump_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').txt
wc -l dump_'$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')'.txt
```

Comment: Your script doesn't actually appear to use extended globbing. Probably also figure out [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove de quotes that prevents shell interpretation:

```
dump_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').txt
```